# BeforeAll Method isn't being triggered

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit5

I am using spring boot, kotlin and junit5. I have a test class and when I use `@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)` 
@BeforeAll function not being triggered, But when I remove this, it gives error for lateinit fields.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class MagnificentClassTest {

  @MockBean
  lateinit var amazonSQS: AmazonSQSAsync

  @MockBean
  lateinit var simpleMessageListenerContainer: SimpleMessageListenerContainer

  @Autowired
  lateinit var magnificentClass: MagnificentClass


  @BeforeAll
  fun setUp() {
    insertApp()
    //insert some data to db
  }

 fun insertApp() {
      val entity = AppJdbc(
          APP_ID = 1
      )

      magnificentClass.insertApp(entity)
    }
```

Comment: RunWith is a JUnit 4 mechanism. BeforeAll is JUnit5/Jupiter. They don’t belong together. Moreover beforeAll methods must be static unless you change the instance lifecycle to PER_CLASS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeforeAll must be on a static method because this is run once per test class.

So for Koltin this would look like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class MagnificentClassTest {

  @MockBean
  lateinit var amazonSQS: AmazonSQSAsync

  @MockBean
  lateinit var simpleMessageListenerContainer: SimpleMessageListenerContainer

  @Autowired
  lateinit var magnificentClass: MagnificentClass

  companion object {
            @BeforeAll
            @JvmStatic
            fun setUp() {

            }

        }
}
```

Please check out https://dzone.com/articles/kotlin-and-junit-5-beforeall

Comment: Edited question, I need to call autowired object also, I can't call it inside companion object

Comment: You can't do this in BeforeAll. Do it in BeforeEach and check if the data is already inserted